# Create scrolling text on empty background, with sound, for presentation?

Tags: video, .srt

I have a sound file with an interview and separate files with a transcription of the interview (one SRT and one text with one sentence per line).

I want to create an animation or video where the transcription scrolls upwards and the sound file is played while the text scrolls. That is, so you can listen to the interview while also reading it. It is nice if it is synchronized but not necessary. The background should be empty/black.

The ultimate goal is to insert the result in a slide in a presentation or PDF.

I am on a Mac.

**What are my (free) options?**

Bonus: it would be nice if the text was aligned to the left (rather than centred).